# How can I create the views pager on top and bottom of the view?

Tags: 7, views, paging, display-suite

I need two view pagers / pagination to sandwich the view content or view results.

Is it possible to duplicate view pagers/pagination ?

What i've done is just printed out the pagers in the template twice; however, that requires me to hardcode the pager.

I need a little more flexibility because I'm required to build / place the top pager in different spots on different pages.

Could this be accomplished with views display (suite) somehow and a code field? I've attempted one and had no luck.

Comment: Not that Ive used it by this module apparently creates another display in your view 'Pager block' which will create a block for the pager.

Comment: What module are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track by editing the views template files. Do you know you can have a different template for each view, or each views display? When you are editing your view there is a link called "theme information" that will help you figure out how to name the templates.

Now, If you mean you need to have the pager in different places on page 1 of this display vs page 2 of the same display, you will have to dig inside the view object to figure out which page you're on in order to figure that out.

I also found this tutorial while Googling the answer:
http://www.adesignforlife.net/articles/drupal-tutorials/solution-how-print-pager-drupal-views-block

Answer (score 0):

I've done this recently for a site. First, you wanna enable twig debugging. Write the file web/sites/development.services.yml with the following content:

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

This will give you hints about available template filenames, in the source code (ctrl+shift+C in the browser to view the source code). Then, in the appropriate template file which for me was `templates/views/views-view.html.twig`:

```
  {% if pager %}
    {{ pager }}
  {% endif %}
  {% if rows %}
    <div class="view-content row">
      {{ rows }}
    </div>
  {% elseif empty %}
    <div class="view-empty">
      {{ empty }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if pager %}
    {{ pager }}
  {% endif %}
```